# Modified urlpatterns in django

Tags: django

I modified url in django, i can use tag `{% url 'student-register' %}` in template but when i call `{% url 'student-reg' %}` it return error reverse-not found, anyone can describe what happened ? this is my code :

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views.home import *
from .views.teacher import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ViewHomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('logout', LogoutAccount.as_view(), name='logout'),

    path('teacher/', include(([
        path('', ViewTeacherHome.as_view(), name='teacher'),
        path('student-register', ViewStudentRegister.as_view(), name='student-register'),

    ], 'exam'), namespace='teacher')),

    path('student/', include(([
        path('', ViewTeacherHome.as_view(), name='student'),
        path('student-reg', ViewStudentRegister.as_view(), name='student-reg'),
    ], 'exam'), namespace='student'))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you specify `student` and `exam` [namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) for nested urls list you should use:

```
{% url 'student:exam:student-reg' %}
```

Comment: Shank u bro, you save my 2 hours